# AngularJS Material: $mdDialog throwing ReferenceError

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-material

Trying to get a dialog box to display after clicking a button to show a users messages. My html:

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" id="header" class="md-toolbar-tools" ng-controller="topbarCtrl as ctrl">
<span flex="15"><img src="assets/imgs/logo.svg" id="logo" ui-sref="sois"></span>
<span flex></span>
<md-button aria-label="Open messaging menu" ng-click="ctrl.showMessages()" class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Open messaging menu">
  <md-icon>messages</md-icon>
</md-button>
```

controller.js:

```
app.controller('topbarCtrl', function($scope, Fullscreen, LoginService, $mdDialog){

this.goFullscreen = function() {
    $scope.fullscreen = Fullscreen.isEnabled();
    if(Fullscreen.isEnabled()) {
    Fullscreen.cancel();
  } else {
    Fullscreen.all();
    }
}

this.logoutBtn = function() {
    LoginService.logout();
}

 this.showMessages = function() {
$mdDialog.show({
    controller: topBarCtrl,
    templateUrl: 'messages.tmpl.html'

})    };});
```

Everything works except the `this.showMessages` function.

When the button is clicked and the function is called, this error is thrown:

`ReferenceError: topBarCtrl is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `$scope` instead of controller

```
$mdDialog.show({
  scope: $scope,
  templateUrl: 'messages.tmpl.html'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So you open dialog box within same controller, 
if you need any function of that controller you can define scope or if you need some value from controller so that you can defin locals scope of model.

for define scope pass this prams

```
 scope: $scope
```

for define local scope of model

```
 locals: {
           items: $scope.items
         }
```

try this